# How to get selected value in dropdownlist by using cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

My code is something like below :

```
public function makeEntryTime($first = '') {
        $j = 0;
        if (empty($first)) {
            $j = 1;
        } else {
            $entry[$j] = $first;
            $j++;
        }

        for ($i = $j; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $entry[$i . ' am'] = $i . ' am';
        }
        for ($i = $j; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $entry[$i . ' pm'] = $i . ' pm';
        }
        return $entry;
    }
```

And here is the drop down list code :

```
$this->Form->select('ClubOpenDay.0.open_time', $this->makeEntryTime(), array("empty" => false, 'class' => 'input-medium'));
```

My problem is I am getting the value like 11 am, 12 am.But I want to make it selected when I will get value 11 am or 12 am from database.Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use [**`FormHelper::dateTime()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::dateTime) or [**`FormHelper::input()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::input) with a type of `time`? ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->select('ClubOpenDay.0.open_time',$this->makeEntryTime(),array("empty" => false,'value' => $value_selected,'class' => 'input-medium')); ?>
```

"$value_selected" is any value with in the input range.

i.e what $this->makeEntryTime() returns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your method is in view which you shouldn't do this. remove public from your function and remove $this to call your function.

try to keep your method inside a controller at least. Here is if you want to keep your method in view.

```
function makeEntryTime($first = '') {
        $j = 0;
        if (empty($first)) {
            $j = 1;
        } else {
            $entry[$j] = $first;
            $j++;
        }

        for ($i = $j; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $entry[$i . ' am'] = $i . ' am';
        }
        for ($i = $j; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $entry[$i . ' pm'] = $i . ' pm';
        }
        return $entry;
    }        

    echo $this->Form->select('selete_id', makeEntryTime(), array("empty" => false, 'class' => 'input-medium'));
```

but if you want to make it MVC.

```
//controller
       function makeEntryTime($first = '') {
            $j = 0;
            if (empty($first)) {
                $j = 1;
            } else {
                $entry[$j] = $first;
                $j++;
            }

            for ($i = $j; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                $entry[$i . ' am'] = $i . ' am';
            }
            for ($i = $j; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                $entry[$i . ' pm'] = $i . ' pm';
            }
            return $entry;
        } 

//page function - for examlpe add() method
       public function add(){
            $this->set('times', $this->makeEntryTime());
       }

//view of add method       
        echo $this->Form->select('time_id', $times, array("empty" => false, 'class' => 'input-medium'));
```